# javascript in html oninput event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code bellow that creates an range input and showing it's value and it works fine except in Edge.

JS

```
function showUnitBar(units) {
    $("#unit_bar").remove();
    $('.svg-container').append('<div id="unit_bar">'
        + '<input type="range" id="unit_input" value="1" min="1" max="' + (units - 1) + '"  oninput="unit_output.value = unit_input.value">'
        + '<output id="unit_output">1</output>'
        + '<input type="button" value="Send Units" id="send_units">'
        + '</div>');
}

showUnitBar(5);
```

HTML

```
<div class="svg-container"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L10r5zvv/46/

The thing is that the value dosen't update in Edge.

I found this code http://jsfiddle.net/L10r5zvv/47/ and it works in Edge but I having problem to solve it to my code because I'm worthless at mixing html and javascript/jQuery.

Comment: What does the console say in edge?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Notice that I added the code you said worked in the correct place [ in the `oninput`]):

```
function showUnitBar(units) {
    $("#unit_bar").remove();
    $('.svg-container').append('<div id="unit_bar">'
        + '<input type="range" id="unit_input" value="1" min="1" max="' + (units - 1) + '"  oninput="document.getElementById('unit_output').innerHTML = this.value">'
        + '<output id="unit_output">1</output>'
        + '<input type="button" value="Send Units" id="send_units">'
        + '</div>');
}

showUnitBar(5);
```

Comment: This looks the exact same.. what did you change? Why would it work? "Try this" is not a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I added this code bellow my existing and now it works with Edge also

```
$('#unit_input').on('input', function() { 
    $('#unit_output').html(this.value);
});
```